# Integrating Codeigniter 2 with phpspec2

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, bdd, phpspec

I want to integrate phpspec2 with CodeIgniter 2. I've succesfully installed phpspec using composer as described on [phpspec website](http://phpspec.net). Now I'd like to integrate it into my CodeIgniter 2 installation. I've found an [article by AniDear](http://blog.anidear.com/2012/11/using-phpspec-with-codeigniter.html)  on this subject and did everything as described. However when I run `bin/phpspec` I get an error:

```
PHP Warning: require(core/Common.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
in  C:\xampp\htdocs\eljotengine\spec\ci_bootstrap.php on line 37

Warning: require(core/Common.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\eljotengine\spec\ci_bootstrap.php on line 37
```

and so on. My file structure looks like this:

```
eljotengine
|-application
|-sytem
|- ... other CI
|-spec
| |- ci_bootstrap.php
```

I am using xampp on Windows 7. My `ci_bootstrap.php` file looks like the one in the above mentioned article by AniDear.

I've tried to change the paths in the `ci_bootstrap.php` file (it seems to be the problem) however it did not change much.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Greets :)

Answer (score 1):

I am having problem with PHPSpec2 too.
Since I have only tried it with PHPSpec (not PHPSpec2), I would suggest you to install PHPSpec  instead. Just change the file composer.json, on the line `"phpspec/phpspec2": "*"` to `"phpspec/phpspec": "*"` , then runs `composer update` again.

Run this phpspec, by using command `vendor\bin\phpspec.php.bat spec` on your project path, whereas "spec" is the folder containing spec files.

And since you're running phpspec from your project directory, I suggest changing content inside  ci_bootstrap.php as follow

```
define('BASEPATH',realpath('system/').'/'); //set absolute path to CI system/
define('APPPATH', 'application/'); //set relative path to CI application
set_include_path(
    get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.
    realpath(APPPATH).PATH_SEPARATOR.
    realpath(BASEPATH).PATH_SEPARATOR.
    'spec');  //adding 'spec' in path, for easily do require 'ci_bootstrap.php' from inside spec files

require BASEPATH.'core/Common.php';
require APPPATH.'config/constants.php';
require BASEPATH.'core/Controller.php';
```